# Navigation html pages liferay portlet

Tags: html, angularjs, liferay, portlet

I'm new in liferay, into my portlet i have html pages with angularJs not jsp.I would ask about how to navigate between these html pages  into my portlet..thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are bit confusing about technology.

1. JSP pages always generate HTML page for your browser.
   It means that you create a JSP page containing just HTML nothing changes (this is correct from a developer point of view... thinking to server job this is not true... but think it is true for our purpose).
2. Client side technology you are going to use is not relevant from a portlet point of view (it can be a problem if your theme uses some not compatible libraries...) but in general whatever library you use (angularjs, backbone etc.).

It means that you can create html or jsp pages containing all the angularjs code you want... and everithing should work fine.

If you want to manage navigation between "pages" in the same portler (e.g. from view.html to details.html) then you have to mind, simplifying, that portlets haven't pages: your portlet will be added in a page of the portal (with its own URL).
So you can rename your html files in jsp files (as I told, nothing changes), then you can tell to portal what is the correct URL to load by JSP code.

For example for making a link to "details.jsp" in your "view.jsp" you can write a code like following:

```
<a href="<portlet:renderURL>
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/path/to/your/details.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>">Text</a>
```

Obviously you can use the `<portlet:renderURL>...</portlet:renderURL>` code wherever you want... because it will be translated in a string before sending to browser... like in javascript `var url = "<portlet:renderURL>....</portlet:renderURL>"`

You shouldn't forget to put these lines at the beginning of yout jsp files:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but the client requires that the pages are html not jsp..The <portlet:renderURL> does not work when we use html file.

Comment: I think what you need is impossible in HTML, because you need to know the portel renderURL. By the way, I don't understand what is the difference for your client to have pages ending in ".html"... because you are writing only html code inside your jsp files (except the way for computing URL)...

Comment: Thanks any way for your answers.. I will talk to the client ;)